# Deleting session variable while avoiding KeyError exception

Tags: python, django

One of the ways to delete a Django session variable is:

`del request.session["sess_variable"]`

This naturally gives a `KeyError` exception in case `sess_variable` wasn't in the `request.session` dictionary.

To handle this exception, one can wrap the line in `try`, `except KeyError`. But is there a separate command one can use that doesn't throw an error if the key doesn't exist?

Comment: `dict.get()` maybe

Comment: @sid-m: that won't delete the value, it'll just retrieve the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [pop](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) the key from the session. If you specify `None` as the default, then you won't get a `KeyError`.

```
request.session.pop("sess_variable", None)
```

Comment: Would one need to do `request.session.modified = True` after this?

Comment: The code above is equivalent to `del request.session["sess_variable"]` while catching the `KeyError`. Both modify `request.session` if the key existed before, so you shouldn't have to set `request.session.modified` for either. The [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) shows when you have to set `request.session.modified = True`, e.g. when you modify `request.session['foo']['bar']`